# A question about nets and sequences

Tags: general-topology

The net is a function $f$ from a directed set $\Lambda$ to a topological space $X$. And for $\Lambda=\mathbb{N}$, $f$ is a sequence. So every sequence  is a net. And now I would like to write a theorem about sequences Theorem: Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $(x_{n})$ a sequence and $x_{0}\in X$. If there is a subsequence of $(x_{n})$ converging to $x_{0}$ then  $x_{0}$ is accumulation point of $(x_{n})$. and we know of that the inverse of the theorem is not always satisfied for general topological spaces if it is not a first countable space.
and the inverse of the theorem is satisfied for general topological spaces if we take any net $x_{\lambda}$ so is
, $x_{0}$ is an accumulation point of the net $x_{\lambda}$ in $X$ IFF there is a subnet of $x_{\lambda}$ converging to $x_{0}$. So if every sequence is a net, how is that IFF possible? Do I miss something?

Comment: Do you mean ‘converse’ by ‘inverse’? Also what if the sequence $x_n$ is constant (Euclidean space$). Reference for some of your claims should be given (The question is not exactely clear)

Comment: The part after "IFF" was presumably intended to be "there is a **subnet** of $(x_\lambda)$ converging to $x_0$." As written, with "subsequence", it's false.

Comment: I meant that the theorem says that for any topological space $X$ and a net $x_{\lambda}$, $x_{0}$ is accumulation point of $x_{\lambda}$ IF AND ONLY IF there is a subnet of $x_{\lambda}$ converging $x_{0}$, but for the sequences only one side of the theorem is okay every topological space that is if $(x_{n})_{k}$ is a subsequence of the the sequence $x_{n}$ and converging $x_{0}$, then $x_{0}$ is accumulation of Point of $x_{n}$, the converse of it holds only for 1st countable spaces. So every sequence is a net , and why the converse of it  does not hold for every topological space @AnyAD

Comment: Thank you sir, so can you please explain it sir? @AndreasBlass

Comment: A subnet of a sequence need not be a subsequence, That might have caused the confusion.

Comment: So where do I miss actually? if every sequence is a net, why the inverse of the theorem does not hold for general topological spaces if we take any sequence ? @HennoBrandsma

Comment: You can have a countable set $\{x_n: n \in \Bbb N\}$ with accumulation point (even limit point) $x_0$ but no subsequence of $(x_n)_n$ converges to $x_0$. This happens in $\beta \Bbb N$ e.g.

Comment: In that last example we **do** have a convergent subnet that converges to $x_0$ though.

Comment: Thank you sir @HennoBrandsma

Answer (score 1):

In any space $X$ we have that if we have a net $f: I \to X$ then

> $f$ has an accumulation point $p$ in $X$ iff it has a convergent subnet to $p$.

If $f$ is a sequence so $I=(\Bbb N, \le)$ we can specialise this to:

> the sequence $f$ has an accumulation point $p$ in $X$ iff it has a convergent subnet to $p$.

But a subnet of a sequence need **not** be a subsequence at all. Examples exist in $[0,1]^{\Bbb R}$ or $\beta \Bbb N$ where we cannot have a subsequence at all, but a subnet does exist. That’s why the version in *first countable* $X$ i.e.

> The sequence $f$ has an accumulation point $p$ iff it has a convergent subsequence to $p$.

does add information and is an improvement.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I cleary got it now, I’ll check the counter examples @HennoBrandsma